# How to configure oauth2 in spring boot BE + spring boot FE + keycloak

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, keycloak

I am new to the oauth2 stuff and I am trying to understand.

I am trying to set up the following:

1. spring backend as a resource server. Basically an API that is secured with JWT token and serves database stuff based on user roles in the token
2. spring boot frontend with thymeleaf that should perform authorization code flow login, obtain an access token and make API calls to the backend with that token.

How should I configure the 2 services to achieve what I want?

I have already tried:

- configuring 2 clients in keycloak, one for the BE, one for FE
- configuring the BE spring boot with spring.security.oauth2.resource server property and tested it and indeed the JWT mechanism is working as expected, I can see the roles that I set up in the keycloak auth server and parse them as authorities

```
security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: baseurl/auth/realms/realmname
          jwk-set-uri: baseurl/auth/realms/realmname/protocol/openid-connect/certs
```

- configuring the FE like:

```
security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          keycloak:
            client-id: id
            client-secret: secret
            scope: openid, profile, roles
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: http://localhost:8082/login/oauth2/code/service-name
        provider:
          keycloak:
            issuer-uri: baseurl/auth/realms/realmname
```

Which works, it triggers the login page of keycloak, I put the user and password in the form and then I dont know how to get ahold of the access token to make api calls to the BE. In the SecurityContextHolder bean in the FE I can only find the ID token, but not the access token.

I am pretty sure I understood the whole concept completely wrong so please help. How should I do this? What am I getting wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution I guess. One can access the access token as documented here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2Client-authorized-repo-service

We can basically autowire the Client Service from Oauth2 adapter and the Oauth2AuthenticationToken from which we can then easily extract the access token!

```
@Controller
public class OAuth2LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService;

    @RequestMapping("/userinfo")
    public String userinfo(OAuth2AuthenticationToken authentication) {
        // authentication.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId() returns the
        // registrationId of the Client that was authorized during the oauth2Login() flow
        OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient =
            this.authorizedClientService.loadAuthorizedClient(
                authentication.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(),
                authentication.getName());

        OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = authorizedClient.getAccessToken();

        ...

        return "userinfo";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post links as answers, but summarize the content and the real solution a little.

Comment: May i know how to exchange the authorization code with the access token? Is it done automaticallly by spring boot behind the scene?